# Is libcheck (.net assembly comparison tool from Microsoft) discontinued?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am trying to download libcheck. But link on Microsoft.com is broken neither it is searchable on Microsoft.com

Is this tool discontinued? 
If yes any other alternative to this tool from Microsoft?

Comment: Many old pages are broken right now while MS rebrands its docs again, sigh.  The new docs pages include broken links that hopefully will be fixed...someday.  Be sure to click the "did this help?" overlay at the bottom of the page, choose NO and then point out the broken link

Comment: this page https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11287
does not have a "did this help?" button :-(